# Why does this not cause a browser redirect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

```
if (selectedddItem.toString().indexOf("6ft with two") > -1) {
  window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
  alert("just passed over");
}
```

The alert window opens so the condition is true... however the browser doesn't redirect?!?!

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Setting window.location is redirecting to google on FF 3.6, IE 8 and Chrome 10

Comment: Have you debugged the value of selectedddItem.toString()? What does it return?

Comment: Do you have another variable anywhere in your program called `window`?

Comment: Just for $h!ts and giggles, have you tried swapping the alert and redirect lines?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the browser you are using, `window.location =` might be not enough.

Try to "full qualify" with `window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";`

However, there is zero jQueryfication in that code :-)

Comment: tried .href and that doesnt work either. just ignores it. im using jquery in the rest of the code surrounding it, thought that might affect things

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href
```

Is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Have your code like this:

```
if (selectedddItem.toString().indexOf("6ft with two") > -1) {
  alert("just passed over");
  top.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
}
```

Make sure you are seeing this alert first before browser redirect otherwise your if condition is returning false.

Comment: Redirect and alert both are in the if block, so changing the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Babar: Changing the order is **NOT** the fix for OP's issue :) I just changed to make sure alert is shown first to ascertain "*if*" condition is returning true. Potential **fix** could be replacing ***window.location.href*** by ***top.location.href*** if JS code is executing from within a frame/iframe.

Comment: I don't see how putting alert before redirect ascertains that if condition is true, and alert after redirect doesn't. Both the statements are in the same block and will only be executed when if is true. So in both philis code and your code, when the popup is displayed it ascertains that the condition is true. Therefore, I commented that it shouldn't matter.